# Shape of the input layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I can't figure out what I should input as the shape of the input layer in my Keras model. The model trains on 1080 vectors with 12288 samples.

I have the following inputs shapes:

```
X_train shape: (12288, 1080)
Y_train shape: (6, 1080)
X_test shape: (12288, 120)
Y_test shape: (6, 120)
layers_dims =[12288,64,64,64,6]
```

and have the NN:

```
def net_model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, batch_size=32):
   model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(layers_dims[0],)))
   for l in range(1,len(layers_dims)-2):
      model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layers_dims[l],activation=activation))
      if dropout:
          model.add(dropout(keep_prob[l]))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layers_dims[-1],activation=keras.activations.softmax))
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])
    model.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
    result_train = model.evaluate(X_train,Y_train)
    result_test = model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test)
    return result_train,result_test

result_train,result_test = net_model(X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test)
```

I am getting this error :

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_10 to have shape (12288,) but got array with shape (1080,)
```

after looking looking the documentation again I tried to use (1080,) as the the input shape but that did not work either.

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_12 to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1080,)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what does "1080 vectors with 12288 samples" mean?  Vectors and samples seem to be referrring to the same thing.  I could understand "1080 vectors of 12288 features" but this leaves me puzzled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape of the training data and labels should be `(num_samples,num_features)` and `(num_samples, num_labels)`, respectively. So the `X` should have a shape of `(1080, 12288)` and not `(12288, 1080)`. To fix this, first transpose the arrays:

```
import numpy as np

X_train = np.transpose(X_train)
Y_train = np.transpose(Y_train)
X_test = np.transpose(X_test)
Y_test = np.transpose(Y_test)
```

And the input shape of Input layer should be `(num_features,)` (i.e. `(12288,)`).